# Black scholes text book

Tags: black-scholes, reference-request

I am looking for an *easy* and *well presented* introduction to Black-Scholes theory and stochastic calculus aimed at undergraduate mathematics students. Please can you recommend a book?

How about Paul Wilmott on QF?

Comment: A Warm Welcome to Quant.SE :-) If you find these answers helpful please upvote them and consider to accept one of them. Looking forward to having you as an active member of this vibrant community :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you [Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019957474X) by Tomas Bjork. It is a standard reference introducing Stochastic Calculus, then Black-Scholes both from a hedging portfolio perspective and a martingale point of view. It has also some nice chapters on American Options, exotic options and Fixed income derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iaqf.org/bookstore
Here you can find the list of books recommended by the professionals in quantitative finance. You can search the recommended books for each topic.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following titles:

- http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3856
- http://books.google.de/books?id=z42E_VIaQbIC&lpg=PR2&pg=PR2#v=onepage&q&f=false
- http://www.markjoshi.com/concepts/
- http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8495

Answer (score 1):

I like [Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521552893) by Baxter and Rennie. It's less technical than Shreve or Bjork, whether that's an advantage or disadvantage is up to you.